# How to delete some characters in r string

Tags: r, character, stringr

I want to delete the character:" (mean (SD))", and I used 3 methods but none of them are successful. I don't know why.

```
 names <- c("Y_OR_N (mean (SD))", "age (mean (SD))", "101004A (mean (SD))", "101016 (mean (SD))", "209003 (mean (SD))", "210005 (mean (SD))", "GFR (mean (SD))", "307001 (mean (SD))", "308001 (mean (SD))", "308014 (mean (SD))")


 names %>% str_remove(pattern = " (mean (SD))")
 names %>% str_replace(pattern = " (mean (SD))", replacement = "")
 names %>% gsub(x = ., pattern = " (mean (SD))", replacement = "")
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can just do `str_remove(names, fixed(" (mean (SD))"))`.

Comment: It seems that you can achieve it by simply deleting everything after the space. Try `sub(' .*', '', x)` **NOTE** I changed `names` to `x` as `names` is a predefined function in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below, using `gsub` + `trimws` (optional), i.e.,

```
trimws(gsub("(mean (SD))","",names,fixed = TRUE))
```

such that

```
> trimws(gsub("(mean (SD))","",names,fixed = T))
 [1] "Y_OR_N"  "age"     "101004A" "101016"  "209003" 
 [6] "210005"  "GFR"     "307001"  "308001"  "308014"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis are special, try escaping them with the `\\`

```
names %>% str_remove_all(pattern = " \\(mean \\(SD\\)\\)")
```